# Compare the content of 2 files in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, file, compare

I want to compare the content of two files in WinForms. Every file contains lines with a name and a number on each line. I want to read from first file and compare it with the second. If the line is not equal i want to extract it and add it to an ArrayList. Look what i've done so far:

```
  Int32 nr = 0;
        String linieinit=" ", liniewrt=" ";
        ArrayList newlines = new ArrayList();
        using (StreamReader fileinit = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "/bontemp" + label_pin.Tag.ToString() + "initial"))
        {
            using (StreamReader filewrt = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "/bontemp" + label_pin.Tag.ToString()))
            {
                while ( (linieinit = fileinit.ReadLine()) != null && (liniewrt = filewrt.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(linieinit + "      " + liniewrt);
                    if (linieinit.Equals(liniewrt))
                    {
                        nr = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nr++;
                        newlines.Add(liniewrt);
                    }
                }
                filewrt.Close();
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/bontemp" + label_pin.Tag.ToString());
            }
            fileinit.Close();
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/bontemp" + label_pin.Tag.ToString() + "initial");

        }
        Console.WriteLine(nr);
        if (nr == 0)
        {
            int pozition = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["DenumireProdus"].Value.ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x, 130 + height);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["produs_cantitate"].Value.ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x + 110, 130 + height);
                height += 15;
            }
            if (pozition > height)
            {
                pozition = height;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (Int32 j = 0; j < newlines.Count; j++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(newlines[j].ToString(), print6B, Brushes.Black, x, 130 + height);
                height += 15;
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion how could i make it work ?

Comment: just as an unrelated code style comment... nested using() statements make me tear my hair out, especially when they span lots of code.

Comment: so what do you need? what's your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)?

Comment: So far, the code you have seems to satisfy your use case.  It also does a lot of extra stuff.  Are you getting any errors or anything?  What are you actually asking?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but it seems that is not reading all the files from filewrt!

Comment: This should be simple.  Read one line at a time from each file.  Convert the line into a string.  Compare String A to String B using the String.Equals method.  If they are not the same string add it to the collection.  This should take at most 10 lines of code.  Please do not read File A while reading File B....that won't get the results you want.

Comment: @Ramhound  Read his code sample.  He's doing exactly what you've described.  But he's also doing a whole lot of other stuff.  which is why there's so much code

Comment: on that note, Please don't just dump your code when you ask a question.  Try to post only the relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not reading all the files from filewrt?  You're using `Console.WriteLine()` in your comparison loop.  What is that printing, and what do you actually expect?

Comment: I mean if the filewrt has one more line then fileinit, it does not compare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ to compare both files with each other:

```
var f1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f1Path);
var f2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f2Path);
var diffLines = f1Lines
     .Where ((line, index) => index >= f2Lines.Length || line != f2Lines[ index ])
     .Select((line, index) => line).ToList();
```

On this way you find all lines that are in the first file but not in the second file.

Comment: Is diffLines an array which contains the different lines ?

Comment: @Emil: `diffLines` is a `List<String>`(strong type ArrayList) which contains all lines that are in the first but not in the second file(you can easily reverse it). If you want an String-Array, use `ToArray` instead of `ToList`.

Comment: +1 for clean looking semantic code, but he should be careful if the files are really big because you load them into memory all at once.

Comment: the files are not big and it's the answer i was looking for . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to call .Close() on a stream if you are scoping that stream within a using statement.

Now for the file diffing part, I think this logic is the source of your problem:

```
if (linieinit.Equals(liniewrt)) 
{ 
    nr = 0; 
} 
else 
{ 
    nr++; 
    newlines.Add(liniewrt); 
}
```

Here is the bug - If all the lines are different but the last line is same, your "nr" will be set to zero. And further down you check if (nr == 0) , instead you may have two variables one for numberOfSameLine and other for numberOfDifferentLines or you can replace the if logic with if(newLines.Count >0) - depends on your app logic.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that too.  It seemed bizarre.  I had assumed that it had some other meaning that i might not have been aware of

Answer (score 0):

After reading the thread of comments, I think I know what you're looking for.

You're while statement:

```
while ( (linieinit = fileinit.ReadLine()) != null && (liniewrt = filewrt.ReadLine()) != null)
{
```

After you've reached the end of `fileinit`, your condition will stop evaluating to true.  If you want to continue adding lines from `filewrt` to `newlines`, you can just loop through the rest of filewrt.

```
nr++;
newlines.Add(liniewrt);
while((liniewrt = filewrt.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    nr++;
    newlines.Add(liniewrt);
}
```

you can make your own decisions about whether you want to keep the `nr++` lines in or not.